# Effect typing when switching slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the slider need realize the effect of "typing" when you switch slides. I use Slick Slider for slider. Work example http://test2.hotweb.com.ua/webbit/.

HTML:

```
<div class="header-slider-wrap">

    <div class="header-slider">
        <div class="slider-nav__left nav-btn-slider">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175"><path d="M145.188 238.575l215.5-215.5c5.3-5.3 5.3-13.8 0-19.1s-13.8-5.3-19.1 0l-225.1 225.1c-5.3 5.3-5.3 13.8 0 19.1l225.1 225c2.6 2.6 6.1 4 9.5 4s6.9-1.3 9.5-4c5.3-5.3 5.3-13.8 0-19.1l-215.4-215.5z"/></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-nav__right nav-btn-slider">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175"><path d="M360.73 229.075l-225.1-225.1c-5.3-5.3-13.8-5.3-19.1 0s-5.3 13.8 0 19.1l215.5 215.5-215.5 215.5c-5.3 5.3-5.3 13.8 0 19.1 2.6 2.6 6.1 4 9.5 4 3.4 0 6.9-1.3 9.5-4l225.1-225.1c5.3-5.2 5.3-13.8.1-19z"/></svg>
        </div>

        <ul class="slider-item-list">
            <li class="slider-item" style="background-color: #6495ED">
                <div class="slider-text-wrap">
                    <div class="slider-text"  data-text='Example text 1'></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="slider-item" style="background-color: #BA55D3">
                <div class="slider-text-wrap">
                    <div class="slider-text"  data-text='Example text 2'></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="slider-item" style="background-color: #8DEEEE">
                <div class="slider-text-wrap">
                    <div class="slider-text"  data-text='Example text 3'></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 printTextSlider();

function printTextSlider() {
    var $btn = $('.nav-btn-slider'),
            $ul       = $('.slider-item-list'),
            $activeLi = $ul.find('.slick-active'),
            $text     = $activeLi.find('.slider-text');

    $text.addClass('is-active');
    printText($text);


    $btn.on('click', function() {

        var $activeLi = $ul.find('.slick-active'),
                $siblings = $activeLi.siblings().find('.slider-text'),
                $text     = $activeLi.find('.slider-text'),
                id        = $text.attr('id');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $siblings.removeClass('is-active');
        }, 1000);


        $text.addClass('is-active');
        printText($('#'+id));


     });
   }

   function printText(el) {
     var a = el.data('text');
     a = a.split('');

     console.log(a);

     el.text('');

     var c = a.length;

     j = 0;

     setInterval(function() {
        if(j < c) {
            el.text(el.text() + a[j]);
            j++;
        } 
        else {
            el.removeClass('after-line');
        }
    }, 100);
 }
```

Style(sass):

```
.slider-text-wrap {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 230px;
}


.slider-text {
  font-size: 36px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**Proble:** when you switch slides, the text displayed is not correct.
Where I'm wrong?

---

**UPDATE**: I found some interesting plugin **typed.js** and rewrite js code for this:

```
printTextSlider();

function printTextSlider() {
    var $btn    = $('.nav-btn-slider'),
        $ul     = $('.slider-item-list'),
        $active = $ul.find('.slick-active'),
        $span   = $active.find('.slider-text'),
        text    = $span.data('text');

    $span.typed({
        strings: [text],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        startDelay: 1300,
        showCursor: false,
    });


    $btn.on('click', function() {
        var $active = $ul.find('.slick-active'),
            $span   = $active.find('.slider-text'),
            text    = $span.data('text');

        printText($span, text);
    });
}

function printText(el, text) {
    el.typed({
        strings: [text],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        startDelay: 1800,
        showCursor: false
    });
}
```

**It's work!**